# Python BeautifulSoup No Output

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm testing out BeautifulSoup through Python and I only see this '[]' sign when I print this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.theweathernetwork.com/ca/weather/british-columbia/vancouver')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
week = soup.find(id='seven-day-periods')
# print(week)

print(week.find_all('li'))
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If you are getting an empty list which means there is no id 'seven-day-periods' which has li elements.

Comment: seven day period may not have any list

Comment: Thanks, but even if I try week.find_all('class'), it also shows empty class so I'm not sure what the problem is..

Answer (score 1):

There are no li as you can see from the weeks content:

```
<div class="sevenDay" id="seven-day-periods"> 
<!-- Legend: show only when data is loaded --> 
<div class="wx_legend wx_legend_hidden"> 
    <div class="wxRow wx_detailed-metrics"> 
        <div class="legendColumn">Feels like</div> 
    </div> 

    <div class="wxRow wx_detailed-metrics daytime"> 
        <div class="legendColumn">Night</div> 
    </div> 

    <div class="wxRow wx_detailed-metrics nighttime"> 
        <div class="legendColumn">Day</div> 
    </div> 

    <div class="wxRow wx_detailed-metrics"> 
        <div class="legendColumn">POP</div> 
    </div> 

    <div class="wxRow wx_detailed-metrics"> 
        <div class="legendColumn">Wind ()</div> 
    </div> 

    <div class="wxRow wx_detailed-metrics"> 
        <div class="legendColumn">Wind gust ()</div> 
    </div> 

    <div class="wxRow wx_detailed-metrics daytime"> 
        <div class="legendColumn">Hrs of Sun</div> 
    </div> 

    <div class="top-divider2"> </div> 
</div> 
<div class="divTableBody"> 
</div>
```

You may have got it mixed up when it is displayed in html. I believe what you are trying to obtain is the values inside legend column. This can be obtained using:

```
for x in week.find_all('div','legendColumn'):
    print(x.findAll(text=True))
```

Thus now your code will be

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.theweathernetwork.com/ca/weather/british-columbia/vancouver')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
week = soup.find(id='seven-day-periods')

for x in week.find_all('div','legendColumn'):
    print(x.findAll(text=True))
```

Where the output is

['Feels like']

['Night']

['Day']

['POP']

['Wind ()']

['Wind gust ()']

['Hrs of Sun']

Comment: Thanks so much. Even if I try week.find_all('class'), it also shows empty list, but the columns are created as a 'class', so I'm slightly confused..

Comment: @James Happy to help! Good luck!